# Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText','int'

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, operator-keyword

I'm doing an app for Android that will generate a random number between 1 and 10,000 and compare it to an EditText inputType:number and then in a TextView tell if it is bigger or smaller.

But when I try to make it, android studio returns an error

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText','int'

Here's the code:

```
package com.boodle.guessthenumber;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
   }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

        public void guess (View view){

        EditText textguess = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.textguess );

        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulto);

        int rand = (int) (Math.random()*10000+1);

        if (textguess > rand) {
            result.setText(textguess.getText() + "is too big" );
            }

        if (textguess < rand) {
            result.setText(textguess.getText() + "is too small" );
            }

        }
```

Comment: You are comparing an `EditText` object to an integer, how does that even make sense? how hungry are you compared to a cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a comparison operator to (reasonably) compare an integer and an instance of the EditText class.

Here, you want to get the number that your EditText contains:

`String guessStr = textguess.getText().toString();`

Then, to get the actual integer value to compare with,

`int theGuess = Integer.parseInt(guessStr);`

`EditText` is a complex object with lots of fields, while `int rand` is just an integer. It doesn't make sense to compare the entirety of an EditText object, with all of its various fields, with just a number.

In this case, you have to pick out the text that your user entered into your `EditText` field -- which will always be a `String` even if you've specified that it's a number-only field -- then use the `Integer` class' `parseInt` method to convert the `String` into something you can compare with an `int`.

Another problem with your code, if your aim is the archetypal 'guess the number' game:

Every time your user will try to guess, they'll be checking their guess against a new random number every single time, since you generate the number they're trying to guess every single time in the `guess()` function.

Comment: It solutioned the problem, and i apologize because i'm a newbie but i didn't realize that the random number its going to be generated every time, so thank you both.@CyberGeek.exe

Comment: @Rookie if this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it as the solution: [Why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [How](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

1) you can not assign views out of the onCreate. What you can do is declare class-wide view objects and then assign them with findviewbyid() in the onCreate so you can use them class-wide.

2) to get the number to compare you first need to do input = (EditText object).gettext.toString() and then entery  = Integer.parseInt(input). After that you can compare the numbers.

Sorry about the formating, I am using the app.